# How to avoid warnings when calling super.attached() in polymer behavior

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I find out that I need to call `super.attached()` inside polymer behaviors ([documentation](https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/behaviors) remains silent about that). When I do this the WebStorm shows me the warning `method 'attached' is not defined in superclass`. My behavior implements only `PolymerBase` but lifecycle callbacks are not defined there. How to avoid the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attached()` is from the `Element` class in `dart:html`, just add it to the implements clause.